# detailed output for nnet function in R

Tags: r, optimization, neural-network

I am using the `nnet` function from the `nnet` package in R to develop a feed-forward multilayer neural network.  I am interested in obtaining more detailed output of the prediction error associated with the output after each training iteration.  Setting the trace argument as TRUE (default) will give me the prediction error after each set of ten training iterations.  However, I'd like to get the prediction error after every iteration rather than after each set of ten.

Using a modified portion of the example code from the help file shows the initial prediction error, the prediction error after 10, 20, etc. iterations and the final prediction error after the maximum number of iterations is reached:

```
data(iris)     
ir <- rbind(iris3[,,1],iris3[,,2],iris3[,,3])
targets <- class.ind( c(rep("s", 50), rep("c", 50), rep("v", 50)) )
samp <- c(sample(1:50,25), sample(51:100,25), sample(101:150,25))
ir1 <- nnet(ir[samp,], targets[samp,], size = 2, rang = 0.1,
                 decay = 5e-4, maxit = 50)
```

The output:

```
# weights:  19
initial  value 55.824151 
iter  10 value 49.096486
iter  20 value 37.871175
iter  30 value 25.536477
iter  40 value 1.498461
iter  50 value 0.954119
final  value 0.954119 
stopped after 50 iterations
```

Using a workaround, I can get the error after each training iteration:

```
errors<-NULL
for(i in 1:50){
  set.seed(50)
  mod<-nnet(ir[samp,], targets[samp,], size = 2, rang = 0.1,
           decay = 5e-4, maxit = i)
  errors<-rbind(errors,c(i,mod$value))         
  }
```

For obvious reasons, the workaround is very inefficient and I am wondering if its possible to tweak the source code to return the error after each training iteration rather than after each set of ten training iterations.  I've tried tweaking the code for nnet.default but have had no such luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I deleted my answer but it's not hard to modify the source of nnet to do what you need. Grab the source [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/index.html). Then in `nnet.R` look at `tmp` and just append that to a `data.frame` of similar structure. Instead of returning `net` change it to your new data.frame

Comment: Seems easy enough but I don't have much experience modifying source code.  I've found the `tmp` object in `nnet.default` but I don't know how to make the changes, then reinstall the package.  Furthermore, I'm not sure how to modify `tmp` to append to a `data.frame`.  Any help is appreciated...